# C# button click once a day

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.GetLeft.Value = invited.GetInviteCountByWeb().ToString();
            HttpCookie oldCookie = Request.Cookies["Time"];
            if (oldCookie != null)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == Convert.ToDateTime(oldCookie.Values["GetTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                {
                    this.IsGet.Value = "false";
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("Time");
                    newCookie.Values.Add("GetTime", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24.0);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but it's not working, the oldcookie is null when browser is closed everytime..
so how can i set button click once a day??

Comment: What are you trying to do? In general you can't rely on the browser to hold onto persistent cookies as you can tell the browser to delete them when the browser is closed anyway.

Comment: Why are you using the nullable property `this.IsGet`? What class encapsulates this method?

Comment: I added ASP.NET tag to clarify. This is a bad approach anyway, you have to store the information server-side (a DB comes to mind) not in a cookie. What if user automatically clears cookies every time he/she closes the browser ?

Comment: You don't have to delete cookies for this approach to fail: what if there are different users, or the user uses different browsers/computers (home / office) - then that "other" cookie is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your else statement is at wrong place, try like this;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.GetLeft.Value = invited.GetInviteCountByWeb().ToString();
        HttpCookie oldCookie = Request.Cookies["Time"];
        if (oldCookie != null)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == Convert.ToDateTime(oldCookie.Values["GetTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            {
                this.IsGet.Value = "false";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("Time");
            newCookie.Values.Add("GetTime", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24.0);
            Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: not working,refresh the browser it shows var , but restart the browser,the oldcookie is null...

Comment: can you show me another method that limit the user can click the button once a day ??